# Headers disappear when I import csv file to Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

A well known fact, when I import a csv file manually into MatLab, the program automatically recognizes which row is the header row and chucks it out when creating a cell array from csv file. This usually is quite useful because it enables the user to deal strictly with the contents of the cell array. However, in this particular situation, I would like to retrieve and reference the header values in my code. Where does MatLab put this header information upon import? Does it simply delete it? How can I reference it?

THanks

Comment: Which method do you use to read your data? There is more than one possibility to read csv files in Matlab. How does your csv look like? Numeric data and text in the headline?

Comment: I am right clicking on the file and selecting 'Import'. Then within the import dialog I am selecting "Cell array". My csv has mixed text and numeric data, the headlines however are all text.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html), which works well, make sure to specify your delimiter (tab, comma or space). It can also return just the header line.

Comment: It is not strictly necessary to specify a delimiter for `importdata`. It also does not return just the header line, the optional `headerlinesOut` output returns the number of detected header lines. The detected text headers will be included in the `colheaders` and `rowheaders` fields of the output data structure. Any text data will be in the `textdata` field and numeric data will be in the `data` field.

Comment: Thanks for the more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As  "900" suggested, `importdata` is handy.   Here's a snippet I've used to turn the data into a struct, for example.

```
tempfil = importdata(filnam);
%% build struct from loaded file. remember to rename the output struct
for i = 1:numel(tempfil.colheaders)
        your_name_here.(tempfil.colheaders{i}) = temp.data(:,i);
    end;
```